# Which libraries exist for PDB (symbol file) generation?

Tags: debugging, symbols, pdb

I know that there are many libraries that parse PDB files and allow extracting debug information from them.

For a project I am working on, I need to generate PDB files. Are there any publicly available libraries that can do that?

Answer (score 2):

microsoft recently released some headers in github to help the clang / llvm toolset take a look [Microsoft Pdb Information in GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/microsoft-pdb)
[clang llvm codeview emission rfc mailing list thread](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-dev/2015-October/045780.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you manage to produce CodeView info (which is partially documented/RE'd) or DWARF, you can try this project: https://github.com/rainers/cv2pdb